# Bash fails with operand expected error

Tags: bash

I have this `.sh` file:

```
export WAS_BINARY_DIR="/opt/ibm/was"
export PROFILE_NAME="Dmgr01"
export WAS_PROFILE_DIR="/var/apps/was8nd/profiles"
export PROFILE_TYPE="management"
export CELL_NAME="Cell01"
export NODE_NAME="Cell01Node01"
export SEERVER_TYPE="DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER"
export HOST="localhost"
export START_PORT="10000"
export ADMIN_USER="wasadmin"
export ADMIN_PASSWORD="wasadmin"
$[WAS_BINARY_DIR]/bin/management.sh -create -profile $[PROFILE_NAME] -profilePath $[WAS_PROFILE_DIR]/$[PROFILE_NAME] -templatePath $[WAS_BINARY_DIR]/profileTemplates/$[PROFILE_TYPE] -serverType $[SERVER_TYPE] -cellName $[CELL_NAME] -hostName $[HOST] -nodeName $[NODE_NAME] -startingPort $[START_PORT] -isDefault -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName $[ADMIN_USER] -adminPassword $[ADMIN_PASSWORD]
```

When I run `bash -x <file>`, I get this:

> createDMGR_node.sh: line 12: /opt/ibm/was: syntax error: operand
>   expected (error token is "/opt/ibm/was")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$[var]` to refer to the variable `var`. But this is not correct, you enclose the variables with `${}` if necessary:

```
${WAS_BINARY_DIR}/bin/management.sh -create -profile ${PROFILE_NAME} -profilePath ...
 ^              ^                                     ^            ^
```

instead of

```
$[WAS_BINARY_DIR]/bin/management.sh -create -profile $[PROFILE_NAME] -profilePath ...
```

Note there is no need to `${}` in this case, but however it is good practice to quote them:

```
"$WAS_BINARY_DIR"/bin/management.sh -create -profile "$PROFILE_NAME" -profilePath ...
```